# In Jdbi3, how can I use bindBean() for same field?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I have Java code:

```
String updateSql = "UPDATE table_name SET field_two = :field_two"
                + " WHERE field_one = :field_one AND field_two <> :field_two"; 
handle.createUpdate(updateSql)
    .bindBean(myBean)
    .execute();
```

```
@Data
public class MyBean() {
   private String fieldOne;
   private String fieldTwo;
}
```

When Jdbi tries to bind the field_two the second time, it throws UnableToCreateStatementException: Missing named parameter field_two in binding.

How can I bind the field_two appeared multiple times in the query using bindBean()?

Comment: Does it work if you use `:fieldOne` and `:fieldTwo` as parameters in the query?

Comment: @Henning Not working either. The second field_two binding will throw UnableToCreateStatementException

Comment: If I use the suggestion made by @Henning I cannot recreate your problem. The named parameters need to match the Java field names - not the database table column names. The fact that you get `UnableToCreateStatementException` when you use the (apparently) correct field names suggests a problem somewhere else, not shown in your question.

Comment: @andrewJames Yes. That was a silly mistake. The field name was not matching up, I was using the column name which is wrong. Please add an answer! :D

Comment: Glad you solved it. You are welcome to [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for this. That way, you can explain exactly how you fixed the issue, for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the binding needs to have the same name with the field name:

```
String updateSql = "UPDATE table_name SET field_two = :fieldTwo"
                + " WHERE field_one = :fieldOne AND field_two <> :fieldTwo";
```